# Making a multi-tiered program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on an assignment in which I need to combine two programs that I have created into one functioning program. The end result I am hoping for is a program that once launched, opens a log in window, then once logged in, the user gets to play a tic tac toe game. Basically I just was wonder how to have a window within which when you click a button, a new window opens that can run extensive code.

Comment: Since you've tagged this as Java, which Java APIs have you looked at for your user interface? Better yet: refine your question by telling us what you have researched so far, what you've tried, and posting an example that you need help with

Comment: To get help, you need to demonstrate some effort towards solving the problem. What resources have you looked into for doing this? Do and try to figure this out, then come back when you a specific question you are stuck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `Swing` framework, Create a second `JFrame` and set its visibility to false, and when the button is clicked, set it `visibility` to `true`.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private JButton jbt = new JButton("Open Window");
    private AnotherFrame jfrm = new AnotherFrame();

    public MyFrame(){
        add(jbt);
        jfrm.setVisibility(false);
        add(jfrm);

        jbt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                jfrm.setVisibility(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private AnotherFrame extends JFrame {

        public AnotherFrame(){

       }

    }
}
```