# How to Have Multiple windows in Java

Tags: java, swing

I've written/Windowbuilder created the code for two windows in java. What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to get the second window to pop up when I run what I want to be the main class. The ChristmasTree class is my main, and the ControlWindow is the secondary one I want to pop up when I run ChristmasTree. I'm unsure of what to put into ChristmasTree, as using Windowbuilder has added code like run() and the initialize bit which is a little beyond my learning so far. 
Here's the opening code for ChristmasTree -

```
public class ChristmasTree {

private JFrame frame;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ChristmasTree window = new ChristmasTree();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ChristmasTree() {
    initialize();
}
```

And Here's the code for the ControlWindow -

```
public class ControlWindow extends ChristmasTree {

private JFrame frame;
private boolean isSnowSelected = false;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ControlWindow window = new ControlWindow();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public ControlWindow() {
    initialize();
}
```

I've left out the other stuff like imports and the bulk of the code to save space and time :)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843693/making-a-multi-tiered-program/19843949#19843949_)

Comment: Thanks Too! I was searching for things like multi window or second window. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename your main in the other window to `createWindow` and remove the argument.

Then in your tree class you can call

```
ControlWindow.createWindow();
```

Or in whichever order you want. In any case, if you replace main with some other name, you can call that at any time. Actually, you can call main as well, but it's generally discouraged.