# Java, swing opening new JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have this piece of code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame {
private PlaneUI planeui;

public GUI(PlaneUI planeui) {
    this.planeui = planeui;
}

//We have put the code that creates the GUI inside a method
public GUI() {
   start();
   planeui.display();
} ...
```

This is just a test and I need the method "planeui.display" to work when the program starts, together with the method "start();" which already works.

```
public final class PlaneUI extends JFrame {

public void display() {
    //Creates a new JPanel object
   JPanel panelStart = new JPanel();
   getContentPane().add(panelStart);

   //Changing the default layout from Flowlayout to absolute
   panelStart.setLayout(null);

   setTitle("Reservationer"); //Sets the window title
   setSize(236, 256); //Sets the default size of the window
   setLocationRelativeTo(null); //Start location of the window (centered)
   setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Exits the window
}
}
```

I have imported the needed libraries and I feel like the problem lies in an object that isn't created correctly since I get a nullpointerexception. I tried running this planeUI class in the main method and it worked correctly. I just can't get it to work this way..

Comment: See [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843693/making-a-multi-tiered-program/19843949#19843949) For using multiple frames.

Comment: In addition to setting the panel visible, do you have any components in the panel? According to [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).
1) Set the container's layout manager to null by calling setLayout(null).
2) Call the Component class's setbounds method for each of the container's children.
3) Call the Component class's repaint method.

Comment: `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` will terminate the JVM, so when you close the `PlaneUI`, it will exit your application

Answer (score 2):

In function `PlaneUI.display()` add one last line `setVisible(true)` because your adding everything but not displaying anything

Answer (score 1):

you have to add this into your `display()` method:

`setVisible(true);`

Otherwise, all you are doing is setting all the aspects of the JFrame and adding the JPanel to it. You have to make it visible afterwards.